# 'Site' object has no attribute 'flatpage_set' - Django sitemap framework

Tags: python, django

I am trying to setup the sitemap for my site.

I added to my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import FlatPageSitemap, GenericSitemap
from home.models import Gesuch
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
info_dict = {
    'queryset': Gesuch.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'added',
}
sitemaps = {
    'flatpages': FlatPageSitemap,
    'gesuch': GenericSitemap(info_dict, priority=0.6),
}
```

and

```
(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

I followed every step in the docs.. but now if i go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml` i am getting this error:

```
'Site' object has no attribute 'flatpage_set'
```

Flatpage is supposed to return `<loc>` part of sitemap.xml, i think..

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't have django.contrib.flatpages in your INSTALLED_APPS.